# What's causing this ClamAV error?

Tags: libraries, antivirus, clamav

I'm using ClamAV within a script to scan a selection of directories. The command used is `clamscan -ri "$dir"`. Recently I've encountered the following error message:

```
LibClamAV Warning: SWF: declared output length != inflated stream size, 169900 != 25538
```

It doesn't cause a fatal error, and only appears once, though I've not been able to identify which directory is producing this error.

Using ClamAV 0.9.33/24547 on an Ubuntu 14.04 server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means it found a SWF (=compressed flash file) that claims it would be of a size  169900 when uncompressed but appears to actually be of size 25538.

ClamAV is basically telling you it found a file that is supposed to be an SWF that is not an SWF.